# Settling on a data type

Tags: c++, api

I am designing a multipurpose C++ math library that will be used to create interfaces, games and so on. Unfortunately I am stuck with a design dilemma and need some opinions. The math library contains the usual Vector, Math, Matrix classes but I can't settle on whether to use floats or doubles.

Can someone list a couple of drawbacks with going all float or all double. Is the world just going towards using all doubles and should I even bother with floats?

With that in mind, are there any architectural advantages I should be looking at, for instance, will using doubles be better to use on 64 bit systems, will floats be better for 32 bit systems (What about with SIMD operations?)

What would be the ideal way to design such a system?

Comment: Simple: use templates. That way, you can allow both.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

1. Use templates
2. Use a typedef

These allow you to change the type. Having the option to use both types is better than only using one.

Comment: Those have been my two approaches in the past (templates for more generic, library stuff, typedefs for application-specific classes). My biggest problem has been finding a good name for the typedef type.

Comment: @aib: 'T' and 'value_type' are common.

Comment: `typedef float T;`? Nah, I think I'd rather name it `float_t` and put the typedef in a `common.h` or `application.h` file.

Comment: @aib `float_t` is reserved by POSIX. `float_type` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your work is engineering- or science-related and needs high-precision results, there is no advantage to using `double` for graphics programming. Stick with `float`.

Note that game engines pretty much universally use `float`. While CPUs tend to work with high precision by default, GPUs work with the precision you specify and are much faster working with `float` than with `double`; likewise for SIMD instruction sets. Note also that OpenGL ES 1.1 and 2.0 don't even support `double`.

Answer (score 0):

In the Microsoft compilers that I use, there is no float math library.  If you pass a float to a math function, it is promoted to double.  Then you have to cast the result back to a float.  So, you might as well go with double everywhere.  (If you are in this environment).

[EDIT] Of course, if you have an array of 10,000 floating point values, then using float will save a significant amount of memory.

Comment: You must have an odd SKU. My copy of Visual Studio has the whole gamut of `sinf`, `tanf`, `atan2f`, etc. It also has SIMD intrinsics that explicitly compute using the specified precision.

Comment: @MarceloCantos: I think some of the C++ math library functions dont have float overloads.  You listed C math library functions.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Every one I've looked at (fmod, sin, cos, asin, tan, atan, atan2, log, log10, exp) has C++ overloads for float. Which ones are you thinking of?

Answer (score 0):

Floats are smaller (= faster to read/write from memory and to transfer from/to graphics casrd), faster for certain operations (divisions and square roots), 4 floats fit nicely into a single SIMD register (homogenous coordinates), and have adequate precision for games. There is no speed difference between float/double on 32/64-bit systems.

In conclusion: stick with floats. You might want to use a typedef, like `typedef float CoordinateType`.